# How to update or load grub2 themes?

Tags: grub2, ubuntu-one, themes

I need to update the grub2 themes. I already removed unwanted entries in menu by editing grub.cfg file. Now I like to update or load the eye catching themes, I want to know whether any Linux application is available for updating themes or we want to do it manually. Please guide the process for both manual and application.

Answer (score 0):

You should not edit grub.cfg file, rather you should edit 2 files one is `/etc/default/grub` and the other is located at `/etc/grub.d` directory , then you should run following command in terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: But I already edit the grub.cfg in boot/grub/. Now the unwanted entries are working fine, I only want to know the procedure for load nice themes for grub2.